# Advanced clean up/speed up tips?

Tags: windows-7, disk-cleanup

My PC is nearly 2 years old now, and I have noticed it getting slower and less responsive over time. I really don't like the idea of a clean install - mostly because of the amount of downloading and installing after.

This is why I'm looking for ways to clean up/speed up my PC, that go a step further than classic CCleaner and Defraggler.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate on:

- AMD Phenom II x4 965
- ATI HD4890
- gigabyte ga-ma790x-ud4p
- 2x2GB of G.Skill Ripjaws (1600 CL7's I believe, not sure though)
- Seagate Barracuda 640GB, 32MB cache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) and [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) should help you a bit with the more advanced aspects of cleaning up and optimizing your computer. These in conjunction with [Black Viper's](http://www.blackviper.com/2010/12/17/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/) list of services and suggested configurations.

It's difficult to be more specific because the reasons for your slowdown are unique to how you use your computer. But using these tools should give you a good idea what is running on your computer and whether or not it is really necessary to be running.

Comment: I liked [your blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/10/05/a-super-users-toolbox/).

Answer (score 3):

Advanced suggestions have risks, other than what you suggest, uninstall any programs you never use, clean up your Startup menu [using Msconfig](http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html), you can also disable any Non Microsoft Services that you do not need.

Check Control Panel (icon view) > Action Center for any problems found

As suggested Black Viper is a good source for Windows Services but will not cover Non Microsoft Services installed by 3rd party programs. These can be seen in Msconfig, click the Services Tab and tick the "Hide all Microsoft Services" to reveal all 3rd party Services.

[image]

Comment: The first sentence of this answer becomes more and more true as Windows versions improve and are better optimized.